# Can you use google-api-ruby-client with Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)?

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

[Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html) appears to only provide sample code in Java. I run ruby on my servers and wish to use [google-api-ruby-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/) to power my GCM installation instead. Are there any guides on how to do this? I just want "hello world" for GCM using google-api-ruby-client.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind - This doesn't require use of google-api-ruby-client with its more advanced authentication logic, and instead uses the much simpler API Key that can be used with simple POST requests. [From the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/c2dm.html):

> **Server changes**
>
> When the application server receives a GCM registration ID, it should
>   store it and mark it as such.
>
> Sending messages to GCM devices requires a few changes:
>
> The request should be sent to a new endpoint:
>   https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send. The Authorization header of
>   the request should contain the API key generated during sign up. This
>   key replaces the deprecated ClientLogin Auth token. For example:

```
Content-Type:application/json 
Authorization:key=AIzaSyB-1uEai2WiUapxCs2Q0GZYzPu7Udno5aA

{   "registration_id" : "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",   
    "data" : {
     "Team" : "Portugal",
     "Score" : "3",
     "Player" : "Varela",   }, 
}
```

> For a detailed discussion of this topic and more examples, see the Architectural Overview.